# Ruby scope issues with yield and classes

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, scope, block

I am trying to create my own each method for the array class. Code is as follows:

```
class Array

  def my_each
    i = 0
    while i < self.length
      yield(self[i])
      i += 1
    end
    self
  end
end

my_each {|i| puts i}



[1,2,3,4].my_each
```

This seems to me like it should work correctly. However, I am getting the message

```
"Undefined method my_each for main: Object"
```

I tried moving the block inside the Array class under the method but then got the following:

```
"Undefined method my_each for Array Class"
```

My block and method have the same name so it seems to me like this would be an issue of scope. How exactly do blocks behave with method is being defined within a class? Is it advisable to do something like this or simply include the block directly inside my method?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've defined it in the `Array` context, you need to call it that way as well:

```
[1,2,3,4].my_each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

That calls the `my_each` method defined on an Array instance. You even have this later in your code, but the earlier error blocked it.

If you got that second error it's because you tried:

```
Array.my_each([1,2,3,4])
```

That's not correct, you'd need to define a class method with the `self.` prefix if you wanted that to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def my_each
    to_enum
  end
end

enum = [1,2,3,4].my_each 
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
enum.map { |n| n*2 }
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
enum.next
  #=> 1 
enum.next
  #=> 2 
enum.next
  #=> 3 
enum.next
  #=> 4 
enum.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

```
Array.instance_method(:to_enum).owner
  #=> Kernel
```

but `Kernel`'s instance methods are documented in `Object`, so see  [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum).

Comment: Is it possible to use map in this form in a scope? I have a array of arrays, and want to work with in a scope.

Comment: @AboozarRajabi, can you give me an example?

Comment: I have an array stored in a field like this: [["2","3"],["4","1"]], suppose that the first elements are user ids (2 , 4), and the second ones are number of their siblings, I want to search for a specific id to see if it's in the array or not, and if it's in the array, what's the second element related to this id?!

Comment: @AboozarRajabi, that doesn't seem to have much to do with this question, but if `arr = [["2","3"],["4","1"]]` and `target_id="4"`, that would just be `_, sibs = arr.find { |id,_| id==target_id };  sibs`. If `arr` does not have an element `[id, sibs]` for which `id==target_id`, `sibs` will equal `nil`.

Comment: See this question plz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614678/rails-how-to-use-scope-to-find-an-element-in-array-of-arrays

Comment: @Aboozar, sorry but I don't know Rails.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with scope, blocks, or `yield`. You have defined your method in the `Array` class, which means that it is available for all `Array`s, but you aren't calling it on an `Array`, you are calling it on `main`, which is a direct instance of `Object`, not `Array`.

> I tried moving the block inside the Array class under the method but then got the following:
>
> ```
> "Undefined method my_each for Array Class"
> ```

In that case, you are calling it on `Array`, which is a direct instance of `Class` and also not an `Array`.

> My block and method have the same name

Blocks don't have names.

```
[1,2,3,4].my_each
```

Here, you are calling the method on an `Array`, but your method requires a block, which you forgot to pass. Therefore, you will get a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the best way is to do this:

```
Array.class_eval do
  def my_each
    # do here what ever you want 
    #( you can us self if you want to handle the current object)
  end
end

[1,3,3,4].my_each
```

or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169538/trying-to-write-my-own-all-method-in-ruby) reference for best answer. hope i it will help you