# Rails: How to use scope to find an element in array of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have an array of arrays like `[["2","3"], ["3","1"], ["6", "1"]]`. The first element of each sub-array is the user ID and the second one is the number of seats the user reserved for an event. 
I want to allow each user to view his reservations by finding his ID in the array. Suppose that I have two models: User and Event. In the User controller, I want to use a scope like `@mybooking = Event.mybooking(current_user.id)` and the problem is how to write the proper scope in the Event model? 
And, if the user is found, I want to use its second element, too.

I tried different solutions but didn't work! Let me know if you think it's not possible using the scope and if you have another kind of solution.

Edit:
As I'm still waiting for a solution that works, I should mention that I'm looking for something like this:

```
scope :mybookings, ->(id){where("reservations.to_enum.map{|n,m| n} ?", id)}
```

or

```
scope :mybookings, ->(id) { where("reservations.map(&:first) ?", id) }
```

These two don't work because of the error I get related to "...." part. 
And, below solution isn't true because I'm calling the Event's scope from User controller and it's not possible to use `reservations` in that controller because this variable is for the Event controller.

Comment: `scope :mybooking, ->(current_user_id) { where user_id: current_user_id }`

Comment: @mudasobwa It's not true! Check the question again!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Event
  scope :mybooking, ->(user_ids) { where(user_id: user_ids) }
end
```

Now it is possible to do in controller:

```
reservations = [["2","3"], ["3","1"], ["6", "1"]]
Event.mybooking(reservations.map(&:first))
```

Comment: I don't think that it works! The array is something like this: reservations = [["2","3"], ["3","1"], ["6", "1"]], how can it find the user ids in the first sub-element of the array? (2, 3, and 6 are user ids)

Comment: @AboozarRajabi see the edit. Just map the array by first element (id) and pass the resulting array into the scope. Let me know whether it works for you

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how you pass the user_id to the scope?! Another problem is that I think you'll get error because you're using the reservations in the other controller! I think you don't have access to it.

Comment: @AboozarRajabi 1. You pass user_ids array, because `reservations.map(&:first)` results in `["2", "3", "6"]`. 2. I am not using `reservations` in any controller, it is you who use it and whose task to pass the `reservations` array correctly to the place, where you'll extract the user ids and pass to the scope :)

Comment: Using reservations.map(...) results in this error: NameError (undefined local variable or method `passengers' for #<UsersController . It's because reservations that is for the Event controller is used in the User controller. Do you know how should I solve this?

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi I do not, because I don't know how you established your controllers, where `reservations` comes from etc.. Basically, you have just make sure to correctly pass the array to scope. That's it