# Rails: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to write this query:

```
@myquery = Event.where("reservations.map(&:first)= ?", current_user.id)
```

but I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: ...ECT "trips".* FROM "events" WHERE (reservations.map(&:first)= 1...
                                                                ^
```

The goal of this query is to find the user ids in the first element of an array of arrays like: [["2","1"],["4","1"]] where 2, 4 are user ids.
I tried different solutions but still have this problem!

Comment: Do you want to get any particular records from `events` table?

Comment: @dnsh Yes! The records that the current_user.id is found as the first element of the sub-arrays of reservations array. For example, if wanted is 1, the records which has ["1", "..."] in reservations like reservations = [["2","3"], ["1","4"]]

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I don't think so! Event is a table and I'm using similar queries but not for array of arrays!

Comment: This is still not clear. Do you just want to filter your array of array  depending on current_user.id? You don't need database query for that.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused but I'm guessing you're trying to create a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Events` (i.e. a `User` has many `Events` and an `Event` has many `Users`).

If so you DO NOT want to do it by storing all the user_ids in the `Event` model and vice versa. What you want to to is create a join table that holds the ids for each

```
#database table
create_table "user_events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "event_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

#join table
class UserEvents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

#user
class User < ActiveRecored::Base
  has_many :user_events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :user_events
end

#event
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_events
end
```

with this structure you are telling your application that `Users` and `Events` are related through `UserEvents` and will have access to all sorts of useful keyword.

For example you could do

```
Event.includes(:users).all.map {|event| event.user.first.id}
```

which will return all the id of the first user from every event, which is what I think you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not a many to many relationship. The problem is that I don't know how to work with an array of arrays and search it's first element. To know more, please see another question of mine which is remained unsolved! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614678/rails-how-to-use-scope-to-find-an-element-in-array-of-arrays

Comment: @AboozarRajabi if the array of arrays is stored in the database you will have to load it into memory to be able to run Ruby code on it. Functions like `map` are not valid SQL. Can I ask why you're storing an array of arrays in the events model?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi I think you are trying to create a many-to-many relationship, but not in the traditional pattern. Would I be correct in saying an Event -> Reservations is one-to-many and Reservations -> Users is many-to-many? (i.e. an Event has many Reservations, a Reservation has one event, a User has many Reservations, and a Reservation has-many Users)